# Background Thread that uses ApplicaitonDBContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to wire up a background thread that will update the database once an hour from Active Directory. I am not sure how to pass the current

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection")));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddScoped<IAppDbRepository, AppDbRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IActiveDirectoryUtility, ActiveDirectoryUtility>();
            services.AddScoped<IActiveDirectoryManager, ActiveDirectoryManager>();

            services.AddHostedService<LdapManager>();
            services.AddScoped<ILdapManager, LdapManager>();

        }

In the LdapManager class I would like to call the UpdateUsers method every hour:

    public class LdapManager : ILdapManager, IHostedService
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration = null;
        private Logging _logger;
        private List<string> ldapConnectorForDirectoryEntries = new List<string>();

        public LdapManager(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;

            UpdateUsers();
            SyncActiveDirectoryUsers();
        }


    public void SyncActiveDirectoryUsers()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
                {
                    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitHandle, (state, timeout) => { UpdateUsers(); }, null, TimeSpan.FromHours(1), false);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

The UpdateUsers() method should be able to call the applicationDBContext.SaveChanges() method.

How can I ensure that the LDAP manger class can use the Application DB context?

Comment: You need to do special stuff to have a long running timer like that in a asp.net environment

Comment: `public LdapManager(IConfiguration configuration, ApplicationDbContext appContext)` ?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - AddHostedService is special stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `class LdapManager : BackgroundService, ILdapManager`

BackgroundService is .NET Core 2.1, there is a code sample available for core 2.0

Inject `IServiceScopeFactory` and override `Task ExecuteAsync(   )`, run a while loop there.

```
while(!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        ...; // do your stuff
    }
    await Task.Delay(myConfig.BackgroundDelay, stoppingToken);
}
```

And here is a good [read about this on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/), including the code sample for 2.0

Comment: do you have a link to the Background Service example for .net core 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

For accessing `ApplicationDbContext` from `HostedService`.

- `DbHostedService`

```cs
    public class DbHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public DbHostedService(IServiceProvider services,
        ILogger<DbHostedService> logger)
        {
            Services = services;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is starting.");

            DoWork();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is working.");

            using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

                var user = context.Users.LastOrDefault();

                _logger.LogInformation(user?.UserName);
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is stopping.");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

- Register `DbHostedService`

  ```
  services.AddHostedService<DbHostedService>();
  ```

Comment: You would almost always want a `Task DoWork()`